# How to show that metrics generate the same topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, let $c$ be a positive real number, and define a new metric $d'$ on $X$ by $d'(x,y) = c \cdot d(x,y)$. Prove that $d$ and $d'$ generate the same topology on $X$.

Okay, so we know that in an open set of $(X, d)$, there exists an open neighborhood of a center point $x$: $N_r(x) = \{y \in X \mid d(x,y) < r \}$. We want to show there exists another open neighborhood centered at $x$ within this open neighborhood just described, but with respect to the different metric $d'(x,y)$. So we basically want to show that $d'(x,y) < d(x,y) < r$. This amounts to showing that $c \cdot d(x,y) < d(x,y) < r$, which is impossible if $c > 1$, so I don't understand what I am really supposed to do.

Comment: Show that any set that is open with respect to the first metric is open with respect to the second one, and conversely.  For the two metrics you gave, differing by just a constant, this should be pretty easy.

Comment: Show that each $d$-ball centered at $x$ contains a $d'$-ball centered at $x$, and vice versa.